# How to get anchor of dockablepane in AvalonDock

Tags: c#, wpf, docking, avalondock

I'm using the third party library AvalonDock to make my GUI. However I'm having problem to get what side a control is docked on. I have tried this.

```
DockableContent doc = (DockableContent)FindName("dcc" + WindowsNames[i]);
DockablePane parent = (doc.Parent as DockablePane);
if (parent.Anchor == AnchorStyle.Top)
```

And this.

```
string dock = DockPanel.GetDock(doc).ToString();
```

But they both always return left no matter what.

How do i get what side a control is docked on?

Answer (score 0):

<s>Are you checked `DockableStyle`?</s>

**EDIT**
I checked this code and worked for me (called this from own `AvalonDock.DockableContent` class):

```
var anchor = ((AvalonDock.DockablePane)(this.Parent)).Anchor;
```

Comment: That property returns dockable not what side it's docked on.

Comment: I still doesn't work for me, may i ask what version your using. I'm using 1.3.